# Hibernate Row is not being saved to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hibernate is not saving my object to the database. Why is this happening? Am I not performing the transactions correctly?
As for the logging of what hibernate is doing it says that
"org.hibernate.SQL - insert into student (email, first_name, last_name) values (?, ?, ?)". I think this means that it doesn't even know what values to put in even though I've created the Student object with the argument constructor.

Here's my code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    

    
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AnimalConfig.class, HibernateConfig.class); // Makes the sessionFactory bean known to the IOC
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory)ctx.getBean("sessionFactory");


        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Student aStudent = new Student("test","TEstinfdasddadas","bob@gmail.com");  //This is a transient instance which means that It's not related to the database, it's temporary
        
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(aStudent);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
    
    
    (( ConfigurableApplicationContext )ctx).close();  //Close the applicationContext
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

}

 }
```

**Here is my Student Entity**

```
@Entity(name = "student") 
@Table(name = "student")  
public class Student {

@Id   
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
@Column(name = "id") 
private int id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

public Student() {
}
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Comment: Can you write session.beginTransaction() in variable and invoke .commit() for that variable? When you call session.getTransaction(), then you get new Transaction object maybe?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you want me to do. "Write session.beginTransaction() in variable", what does in variable mean?

Comment: for example: Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction(); after that not call that session.getTransaction().commit(); try to call tr.commit();

Comment: You should show the code for the student entity. Also increase hibernate logging level and see what actually hibernate is doing.

Comment: Ok I've updated the post and included the Student Entity. As for the logging level I think Hibernate is not even aware of the values of the Student Object I'm asking it to insert. It says 
org.hibernate.SQL - insert into student (email, first_name, last_name) values (?, ?, ?)

I know that It knows which database I'm using as it's creating the Student Table in MySQL automatically for me as I wanted it to.

I dont mean to be that guy but I'm also very new to Hibernate and don't know like the majority of what the logging even means

Comment: That's not how you usually want to save entities to a database, you want to work with Repositories and Spring Data instead. You can create an app with your Student table on https://bootify.io to have a running example.

Comment: Yes I understand that's not the way to do it. I just wanted a fast way to experiment with hibernate, making database operations, executing queries all in my main function.

Comment: Then maybe it would be faster to use the default / Spring Data way? You can add your queries at the repositories with @Query .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't configure Hibernate to do flushing on commit. Try using `session.flush()` before commit.